# How to get Number of bits from Hex

Tags: javascript

For example how do I get 8 from 0x01, or 16 from 0x0001.

I want to know the number of bits a variable has.

```
var someNumber = 0x123456;
var len = whatToDoHere(someNumber);
console.log(len); // => 24 for example
```

Comment: You would need to parse a string not a number as 0x0001 would translate to 1d and that could fit into one byte. Unless you want to know how many bytes would it take to hold the number.

Comment: Numbers don't have differing "number of bytes" in JavaScript.  You might consider `Math.log2()` to get what you want, though.

Comment: `64` ... ... ...

Comment: There is 1 byte in `0x01`, not 8.  Are you interested in *bytes* or *bits*?

Comment: @Pointy just updated the question - you're right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few alternatives:

```js
f1 = n => (Math.log2(n) & -8) + 8                          // log2 (-Infinity & -8 = 0)

f2 = n => ((n >>= 8) && f2(n)) + 8                         // recursion

f3 = n => n.toString(16).length + 1 << 2 & -8              // string length

for (n of [0, 0xff, 0x100, 0xffff, 0x10000, 0xffffff])
  console.log( f1(n) + '\t' + f2(n) + '\t' + f3(n) + '\t0x' + n.toString(16) )
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A number is just a number, it does not have any particular representation attached to it. Even if you say that it would be formatted in base16 (as hex) or base256 (bytes), that doesn't say anything about the number of leading zeroes (as in `0x01` vs `0x0001`). If you know that however, you'd already know how many digits your formatted number has.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to convert to a hex string and then measure the length of the string:

```js
const someNumber = 0x123456;
const hexString = someNumber.toString( 16 );
const numberOfBits = hexString.length * 4;   //each character is half a byte
console.log( "Number of bits: ", numberOfBits );
```

Comment: That sadly doesn't work as expected.
(0x123456).toString().length / 2  // => 7, but should be 24

Comment: Ah sorry, your question said Bytes (and also bits elsewhere). In that case, `someNumber.toString( 16 ).length * 4` should be what you want. Don't forget that 16 in the toString()! I've updated my post to match.